# How can I convert the complete file to a specific format?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, text-processing

I have a file of 1 GB and would like to convert it into a certain format.
The file contains the following URLs:

```
google.com
trafficinviter.com
example.com
```

I would like to convert the complete content in this format:

```
"http://google.com","http://trafficinviter.com","http://example.com"
```

Using Ubuntu. This is exactly the format of PHP array. So I would like to know how I can convert to this format and save to another file.

Comment: @Zanna Hello, the do is the number urls one after another... actually the file is huge. hence I have just mentioned a few sample for asking.

Comment: @Zanna I have edited the question and hope that it will help to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do this in Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'printf "\"http://$_\","' file | sed 's/,$/\n/'
"http://google.com","http://trafficinviter.com","http://example.com"
```

The `-l` removes newline characters from the end of each line (also adds a `\n` to each `print` call which is why I'm using `printf` instead). The `-ne` means "run the script given by `-e` on each line of the input file. The script itself will print `"http://`, the current line (`$_`), and `",`. Then, the `sed` removes the final trailing comma.

---

Alternatively, you could do:

```
$ sed 's#^#"http://#;s#$#"#' file | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$/\n/'
"http://google.com","http://trafficinviter.com","http://example.com"
```

Here, the 1st `sed` will replace the beginning of each line (`^`) with `"http://`, and the end of each line (`$`) with a `"`; the `tr` replaces each newline character with a comma and the 2nd `sed` removes the last trailing comma.

Comment: I want to write the output another file. But I don't know why I am not able to. The output file is 0 byte

Comment: @JafferWilson OK, but how are you doing it? Actually, it might be simpler if you just come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) a second and we can see what's wrong.

Comment: it is simple. just using your solution and  putting `>` and output file name. I thing this should give answer.

Comment: @JafferWilson yes, it should, that's why I asked you to come to chat. There's nothing special here that would stop the file from being created. So come into chat where we can discuss it and you can show me the exact commands you used.

Comment: The first sed command could be simpler with a record: `sed 'sx\(.*\)x"http://\1"x' test.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'`

Answer (score 7):

You could do it like this:

```
tr '\n' ',' < file | sed 's#[^,]\+#"http://&"#g;s#,$#\n#'
```

#### Explanation

- `tr '\n' ',' <file` replace newlines with commas in `file`
- `|` pipe output to
- `s#[^,]\+#"http://&"#g` replace a series of characters excluding comma with the same characters prepended by `http://` and surrounded by "quotes"
- `s#,$#\n#` remove the last comma, replace with a newline

Note: this will fail if the urls have commas, so if that's possible in your case, use [terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/867875/527764) for reliable results

Comment: Swapping `tr` and `sed` would make the command easier to read and also immune to URLs containing commas: `sed 's#.*#"http://&"#' file | tr '\n' ','`

Comment: @ByteCommander I started out that way but I didn't want to pipe again to remove the last comma. Also, that solution is the same as terdon's, so I'm stuck with my post as it is I think :)

Comment: Oh right, the evil trailing comma...

Answer (score 5):

### Awk solution

```sh
awk '{ printf("\"%s\",", $0) }' input.txt
```

PHP allows terminating commas in array literals, if I recall correctly.